# How to launch debugging session command window minimized in Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, command-line, command-line-arguments, commandargument

There's a field for `Command Arguments` in the project properties.

I've tried:

- `/min`
- `/minimize`
- `/minimized`
- `start /min`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I can follow, but do you want to have the debugger launch a command-line application in a minimized console window?

Comment: Yup - exactly - ideally using a Command Argument.

Comment: The *Command Arguments* are passed to the debuggee, while the ones you tried apply to the command interpreter. However, as far as I know, Visual Studio's debugger doesn't launch a command interpreter.

Comment: So you're saying it's up to the application being debugged to handle the Command Argument and minimize the window? Is there not a uniform Windows `minimize this` command argument?

Comment: No. The command line is passed to the [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) API call. If you'd want your application to start minimized, you'd have to pass the appropriate value for *wShow* in the [STARTUPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331.aspx) structure. But that isn't hooked up to the command line. This field is used when creating a shortcut (.lnk), though.